# Bound on Bessel potential

Tags: functional-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $s\in\mathbb{C}$. For a complex number $z$, $Re(z)>0$, consider the Bessel potential
$$K_s(z)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-z\cosh t}\cosh(st)dt$$
I need to prove that, if $|z|\leq 1$, then
$$|K_s(z)|\leq C_s|z|^{-|Re(s)|}$$
where $C_s$ is a constant depending only on $s$.

Comment: You mean $C_s$ depends only on s, right?

Comment: Yes, i need an estimate uniform in $z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cosh(st) = \cosh(\Re(s)t+i\Im(s)t) = \cos(\Im(s)t)\cosh(\Re(s)t),$$
hence:
$$\|\cosh(st)\|\leq \exp(|\Re(s)|t),$$
while
$$\|\exp(-z\,\cosh t)\|=\exp(-\Re(z)\cosh t)\leq\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\Re(z)\,e^t\right),$$
so:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\|K_s(z)\|&\leq&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(|\Re(s)|t-\frac{1}{2}\Re(z)\,e^t\right)\,dt\\&=&\left(\frac{1}{2}\Re(z)\right)^{-|\Re(s)|}\Gamma\!\left(|\Re(s)|,\Re(z)\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
and you can take $C_s$ as:

> $$ C_s =2^{|\Re(s)|}\cdot \Gamma(|\Re(s)|).$$